# Automate testing of a 3rd party control that does not have UI automation support

Tags: telerik, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am looking for less technical / more high level answer for these questions.

I am using a coded UI for automation. The application is a WPF application. There are Telerik radcontrols (3rd party controls) that do not support UI automation.

My question is if UI automation is not supported for these control then what does that mean for me as a tester in terms of next steps?

There were some suggestions I have seen but it is not clear to me what suggestion is for a control provider and what suggestion is for a tester "control consumer".  Kindly elaborate what I as a tester can do to automated from this point going forward.  Also what I can suggest to development on what needs to be done from their end.  The development team states that the controls are 3rd party so they are consumers of these controls.

I have also looked at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/01/05/1-introduction-to-coded-ui-test-extensibility.aspx but am at a loss as to which layer I need to investigate/research.
This resource is great but too technical.

Any guidance on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the telerik controls are not supported for UI automation. What do you see when you use the SDK tools such as UISpy or Inspect? If you see the controls in the tree, then they are somewhat supported.

Comment: I thought Telerik controls supported Coded UI, see eg http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/coded-ui-support.html . Check with your developers on which version of the controls they are using and check the Telerik website for what Coded UI support they have for the controls your application uses.

Comment: According to Telerik http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/1eaa485f-f637-4828-94ac-23f2e49a07ae.html, there are some wpf controls on this list we are using that do not have ui automation support

Comment: The control names are pasted below and the version used by the developer is 2013.2.6.11.40,   
-RadDataFilter 
RadMaskedTextBox
RadRichTextBox 
RadRibbonButtons
RadRichTextBox
GridViewCell